# C# + Automation UI: the easiest way to drag and drop from one control element to another by their Automation IDs?

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, nunit, ui-automation

have some UI Automation tests. 
Two objects -- two nodes of the same Treeview. Have their automation IDs.
Is there a way to drag and drop from one node to another?

```
public void WhenIDragAndDropFromOneToAnother( AutomationElement firstNode, AutomationElement secondNode )
{
     DoMouseLeftPressByAutomationID( element1 );
     DoMouseLeftUnPressByAutomationID( element2 );
}


public void DoMouseLeftPressByAutomationID( AutomationElement element )
{

    System.Windows.Point clickablePoint = element.GetClickablePoint();
    SetCursorPos( (int)clickablePoint.X, (int)clickablePoint.Y );
    mouse_event( MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
}

public void DoMouseLeftUnPressByAutomationID( AutomationElement element )
{
     System.Windows.Point clickablePoint = element.GetClickablePoint();         
     SetCursorPos( (int)clickablePoint.X, (int)clickablePoint.Y );
     mouse_event( MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0 );
}
```

No dragging and dropping happen.